# activate submenu on anchor hover NOT li hover

Tags: html, css, hover

I am trying to activate my sub-menu when hovering on the anchor tag in my ul. It seems to only work when hovering on the li the anchor tag is in. I don't want to restrict the width of my list-items just to get that effect. I've tried several methods like:

a:hover, nav .collapsable a:hover, and removing the "display-block" attributes. Any help will be very appreciated! Thanks

Here is my html:

```
<nav>
              <ul class="collapsable" style="margin-left:-5px; margin-top:-10px;">
              <li>Licensing
              <ul>              
                <li><a href="#Corporate">Corporate</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Individual">Individual</a></li>
                <li><a href="#TBA/DBA">TBA/DBA</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Nonresident">Nonresident</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Name approval">Name approval</a></li>
                <li><a href="#CSRs">CSRs</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Who needs a license">Who needs a license</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Duties an unlicensed person can do">Duties an unlicensed person can do</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Continuing education">Continuing education</a></li>
              </ul>
              </li>
              <li>Business planning
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#Business plans">Business plans</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Marketing plans">Marketing plans</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Perpetuation plans">Perpetuation plans</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Disaster plans">Disaster plans</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Local Chambers of Commerce">Local Chambers of Commerce</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Dos and don'ts of starting your own agency">Dos and don'ts of starting your own agency</a></li>
              </ul>
              </li>
              <li>Financial planning
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#Accounting">Accounting</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Taxes">Taxes</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Insurance for the agency">Insurance for the agency</a></li>
                <li><a href="#E&amp;O">E&amp;O</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Agency financing">Agency financing</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Premium financing">Premium financing</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Trust accounts">Trust accounts</a></li>
              </ul>
              </li>
              <li>Sales and marketing
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#Advertising">Advertising</a></li>
                <li><a href="#agencymarketingtoolkit">Agency Marketing Tool Kit, calendar</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Signage and business cards">Signage and business cards</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Local community services">Local community services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Consumer content">Consumer content</a></li>
                <li><a href="#PIA Creative Services">PIA Creative Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Markets">Markets</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Niche marketing">Niche marketing</a></li>
              </ul>
              </li>
              <li>Office organization
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#Physical space/layout">Physical space/layout</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Furniture">Furniture</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Equipment">Equipment</a></li>
              </ul>
              </li>
              <li>Personnel management
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#Job descriptions">Job descriptions</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Hiring">Hiring</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Testing">Testing</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Personality and aptitude assessment">Personality and aptitude assessment</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Managing">Managing</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Compensation benefits">Compensation benefits</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Group health, dental, life and long-term disability">Group health, dental, life and long-term disability</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Contracts">Contracts</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Employment law">Employment law</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Employee handbook">Employee handbook</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Time management">Time management</a></li>
              </ul>
              </li>
              <li>Internal workflow
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#Procedures manual">Procedures manual</a></li>
                <li><a href="#IwE&amp;O">E&amp;O</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Coverage checklists">Coverage checklists</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Carrier workflow">Carrier workflow</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Binding authority">Binding authority</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Underwriting">Underwriting</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Workflow">Workflow</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Privacy">Privacy</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Files">Files</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Storage/security">Storage/security</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Notices">Notices</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Cyber insurance">Cyber insurance</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Policy writing/proposal template">Policy writing/proposal template</a></li>
              </ul>
              </li>
              <li>Technology issues
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#Agency management systems">Agency management systems</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Computer hardware">Computer hardware</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Software">Software</a></li>
                <li><a href="#E-mailing/faxing/electronic filing">E-mailing/faxing/ electronic filing</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Real Time utilization">Real Time utilization</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Emerald Website Design service">Emerald Website Design service</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Agencyrevolution">Agency Revolution Internet marketing</a></li>
              </ul>
              </li>
              <li>Reference resources
               <ul>
                <li><a href="#PIA website &mdash; Think PIA first">PIA website&mdash;<em>Think PIA first </em></a></li>
                <li><a href="#PIA National">PIA National</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Insurance Department websites">Insurance Department websites</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Department of Motor Vehicles">Department of Motor Vehicles</a></li>
                <li><a href="#National Traffic Safety Council">National Traffic Safety Council</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Glossaries of insurance terms">Glossaries of insurance terms</a></li>
              </ul>
              </li>
              </ul>
           </nav>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
nav li>ul {
/*display: inline-block;*/
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
nav .collapsable li>ul {
display: none;
}
nav li>ul::before {
content: " ";
}
nav li>ul::after {
content: "  ";
}
nav li:hover>ul {
display: inline-block;
}
nav li>ul>li {
/*display: inline-block;*/
}
nav li>ul>li+li::before {
content: " ";
}
```

Comment: You could change your CSS from `nav li:hover` to `nav li a:hover`.  Having said that, all your anchors are the full width of the `li` so I see little benefit in doing so (and the added side-effect of reducing the area on which `:hover` is engaged) - if you add your code to a jsfiddle.net, we can help  with the troubleshooting faster

Comment: I see your point. Maybe if I keep the lengths of my achors based on their text somehow? here is the jsfiddle, hope this helps: http://jsfiddle.net/SteveSerrano/cfzhhery/

Comment: could you also indicate what your desired outcome is? perhaps with a screenshot of a design or hand-drawn image that illustrates your objective?  It's hard to know what is not working and what is working fine with only code...

Comment: ok, so to be more precise, my nav is within a responsive div element, so the width will vary. I want the sub-li in my ul to fire when hovering over the achors text specifically. As you said the achor is the width of the li, which is also the width of its responsive div. It already looks like I want it to(for the most part), I just cant get it to respond how I want it to.

Comment: Your issue right now is that you cant apply :hover to an element that isnt the child of the item being hovered over. The UL element isnt the child of your anchor text. You might want to investigate using jQuery.